# How to add key signature to a string so it can work as an index for an object?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How to add a signature to this interface so typescript will understand that the current value might serve as an index for a certain object I am getting the error of
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type

```js
export interface StateInterface {
  list: {
    current: string;  // itmesA or itmesB
    itmesA: string[];
    itmesB: string[];
  };
  
const state =   
   list: {
    current: 'itemesA'
    itmesA: ['1','2','3'];
    itmesB: ['4','5','6'];
  };
  
 let showItems = context.list[context.list.current][0]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`string` could be anything, but only specific strings can be used to index that object. So that means you could make the keys more specific so that the `current` property can only be one of the right keys.

---

```
export interface StateInterface {
  list: {
    current: 'itmesA' | 'itmesB';
    itmesA: string[];
    itmesB: string[];
  };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRk1QEkU0tc4BvAKDjgBsEBnGALhvobmwFcoUYCk4ByBDAC2wFgEFRcAD5xxUmQCFR3BhOlzObKMgDmAbQC6Abm2I1LdQZhGkZq9wC+1991rYISNjg2YmBOQhCyVAwcPABeLh5mNk46Hl4BIREVXRl5ABobHP04U1EARlE80QAmStEAZlFzArSihxLRABY6gFY6gDYmlrhvb1pGYHgWAAsIAHcSVEkWOHjg1AA6JJhTdeAt1hgN-kFhGHNTAAZzOAB6W7g56ABrFlpaIA)

---

Or more cleverly so you don't have to type the key names twice:

```
export interface StateInterface {
  list: {
    current: keyof StateInterface['list']; // though this makes `current` a valid key
    itmesA: string[];
    itmesB: string[];
  };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgZRk1QEkU0tc4BvAKDjgBsEBnGALhvobmwFcoUYCk4ByBDAC2wFgEFRcAD5xxUmQCFR3BhOlzObKMgDmAbQC6Abm2I1LdQZhGkZq9wC+1991rYISNjg2YmBOQhCyVAwcPABeLh5mNk46Hl4BIREVXRl5ABobHP04U1EARlE80QAmStEAZlFzArSihxLRABY6gFY6gDYmlrhvb1pGYHgWAAsIAHcSVEkWOHjg1AA6JJhTdeAt1hgN-kFhGHNTAAZzOAB6W7g56ABrFlpaIA)

---

Or perhaps with an additional type to make things cleaner.

```
interface SomeLists {
  itmesA: string[];
  itmesB: string[];
}

export interface StateInterface {
  list: SomeLists & {
    current: keyof SomeLists;
  };
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EAywDOY+yA3gFDLLBjb4CCAXMoVKAOYDaAugNwVU0I+AEJMW7bnwC+ZMhAAeAB3RQwVcNHhI0YOJACSG2IhTlKAGwJgmGbHkLEAZKX6UEAVyhQI4JgGsIAE90GDQsXCt8PkopaX4yBHQQQmZdSBs0iENIY20AXhdKZEtCJjMijy8fa2QAcmpaOlqAGlcBRqYOWoBGFtqAJj6AZlquVqL2oVFkLoAWPoBWPoA2UfHkGRkycwg1fAALdAB3fUhMYgLCPQgAOhKwDivIO6sbyu9wLg4ABi5kAHp-sgjio-PhZEA)

---

There's a lot of way to go about this. Which to choose is somewhat opinion based guided by how this type will be used.

Comment: Makes more sense now.